# Override OxyPlot default color palette

Tags: c#, charts, color-palette, oxyplot

I've been making use of [OxyPlot](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot) lately, and was wondering if there is a  way of overriding the default Color Palette of PlotSeries / PlotModel?

I know i can set the color individually for each series, but it would be nice to have an array of color and then apply it to the model / series.

Answer (score 19):

You can change the `DefaultColors` list in `PlotView`'s `Model`:

```
plotView.Model.DefaultColors =  new List<OxyColor>
        {
            OxyColors.Red,
            OxyColors.Green,
            OxyColors.Blue,
            OxyColor.FromRgb(0x20, 0x4A, 0x87)
        };
```

To make it even more easy, `OxyPalettes`'s class methods can be used:

```
plotView.Model.DefaultColors = OxyPalettes.Jet(plotView.Model.Series.Count).Colors;
```

Comment: How would I reference the color FromRgb after creating it?

Comment: @DevDave Why not to save it to local variable? Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the other answer, if you want to use the same set of colors for every plot in your application, you could set those in your xaml resources. If, for instance, you want to use the default [Seaborn palette](http://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html), you could add the following to your `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <x:Array Type="Color" x:Key="SeabornColors">
            <Color>#4c72b0</Color>
            <Color>#55a868</Color>
            <Color>#c44e52</Color>
            <Color>#8172b2</Color>
            <Color>#ccb974</Color>
            <Color>#64b5cd</Color>
        </x:Array>
        <Style TargetType="oxy:Plot">
            <Setter Property="DefaultColors" Value="{StaticResource SeabornColors}"/>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Valid for OxyPlot 2.1 and above

From `OxyPlot` version 2.1.0 and above, the `Plot` class and its associated components have been moved to `OxyPlot.Contrib.Wpf`, as described in the [release information](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/releases).

Hence the `App.xaml` example shall be written as:

```xml
<Application x:Class="Viewer.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:oxycontrib="http://oxyplot.org/wpf/contrib"
             StartupUri="View/MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <x:Array Type="Color" x:Key="SeabornColors">
                <Color>#4c72b0</Color>
                <Color>#55a868</Color>
                <Color>#c44e52</Color>
                <Color>#8172b2</Color>
                <Color>#ccb974</Color>
                <Color>#64b5cd</Color>
            </x:Array>
            <Style TargetType="oxycontrib:Plot">
                <Setter Property="DefaultColors" Value="{StaticResource SeabornColors}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Don't forget to add the `Oxyplot.Contrib*` package from NuGet manager to your C# solution:

[image]